# Filter query with variable list in django

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a three table model like that :

[image]

I want to filter results of a query with a variable list of items for exemple :

```
listTags = ["landscape","green"]
results = ListTag.objects.filter(tag__name__in=listTags).select_related()
```

But the result of that query is all the ListTag objects with *landscape* **OR** *green* but what i want it's a list of ListTag objects with *landscape* **AND** *green*

I saw a lot a of answers about that problem but a lot of them use a static list of tags, what i want it's to filter with a variable listtags list

Edit : the model

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=False, verbose_name=('name'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=False, verbose_name=('name'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ListTags(models.Model):
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='picture')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tag')
```

Comment: It's not clear what's the relationship between the models by looking at your graph, can you show the simplified model code for them please?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Django Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

In your case this could be:

```
from django.db.models import Q

...

listTags = ["landscape","green"]

query = Q()
for tag in listTags:
    query &= Q(tag__name = tag)

results = ListTag.objects.filter(query).select_related()
```

**addition**:
if you want just pictures with tags, then you could use [many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships). But if you want use tags for different types of models, then u need to use [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

In first case models structure could be:

```
from django.db import models

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False, verbose_name=('name'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Picture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False, verbose_name=('name'))
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

With m2m relation Q object will not work, so to get all pictures with landscape and green tags you can use filter chaining:

```
listTags = ["landscape", "green"]

results = models.Picture.objects.all()
for tag in listTags:
    results = results.filter(tags__name = tag)
```

Comment: it works as it should actually, it gets `ListTag` objects wich related to `Tag` objects with names _landscape_ **AND** _green_. But it is impossible to obtain ListTag objects with _landscape_ **AND** _green_ with this models structure, its always will be only one `Tag` object _landscape_ **OR** _green_ related to `TagList`. Thats why results for this code is empty. I think you need to restucture your models and clarify your aim

Comment: Can you give me a way to change my model please ? My aim is to get pictures with some tags that the user can enter

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code below would make this an AND query rather than an OR query:

```
listTags = ["landscape","green"]

filters = {}
for value in listTags:
    filters['tag__name__in'] = value

results = ListTag.objects.filter(**filters)
```